# Restore Stored Procedure from Google Cloud MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I accidentally overwrote a MYSQL stored procedure through the Workbench client connected to a GCP MYSQL instance. I tried restoring a previous backup to recover it, but that only restored the tables - no views or stored procedures.

Is it possible to restore MYSQL SPs from GCP MYSQL backups?